# Mobile First Platform Server - Changing WAS Liberty Path

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I had already installed MFP 6.3

Now, is it possible to change WAS Liberty Install Path  (by editing config files) ?

Please let me know whether there is anyway to do the task mentioned above

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Comment: Installed it where? development? stand alone?

Comment: I installed it on my laptop using IBM Installation Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all.

If you mean that you want to move your WebSphere Liberty installation folder elsewhere, then at least on Mac this is a stand-alone install and you can simply copy-paste the folder anywhere else you want.

If you mean that you want to use a different WebSphere Liberty installation, then go ahead and install another instance using the IBM Installation Manager. You could then copy the usr folder from the original instance into the new one.

If this is not what you're asking, please put some effort and write coherent and **detailed** questions, and do not assume anything. Mention everything.

Comment: Ok, thank you,  I was trying to use different version of 'WAS'

Comment: And a little question,  I had installed WAS Liberty using IBM Installation Manager.  How to logon to WAS admin console?  I could not find the <port_no> and also I don't see 'manageprofiles.sh' in my installed directory to create a dmgr profile

Comment: WebSphere Liberty profile does not come with an admin console like WebSphere Full profile.

Comment: Ok understood.  Are there ways to create 'dmgr' profile on WAS Liberty?  I am google'ing but could not find

Comment: This is not an IBM MobileFirst question - consult the WAS Liberty documentation.